# How to read the Excel data, if I have more than one reference in one column?

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel

I have an Excel file that I need to read in python.
The row needs to be read for each columns in the same way, for all the references in that row.

For instance: In column C, contains 2 references, I need a code or loop to function in such a way that date, id, amount and weight should be same for the first Reference. and also for the second reference, since it is the same date id , amount and weight only reference is different. After that only the loop should go to next row.

[image: screenshot of some spreadsheet cells]

The result should see somehow this way ;

```
Date       ID   References   Amount   Weight
06.05.2022  1  T123  120  100
06.05.2022  1  T456  120  100
07.05.2022  2  T486  145  200
08.05.2022  3  T785  185  154
08.05.2022  3  T985  185  154
08.05.2022  3  T789  185  154
09.05.2022  4  T654  254  246
```

See this screenshot:

[image: another screehshot]

Could you help me to find the right code for this in python?

Comment: What have you tried yet ? Do you encounter any specific roadblock ? or do you not know where to start ?

Comment: Have a look at https://pandas.pydata.org/ it will show you how to read files, and manipulate the data.

Comment: I know, it can be done using for loop, if I have only one data in every cell of an excel file. this case I don't know

Answer (score 0):

With this as my spreadsheet:

[image: Spreadsheet with holes]

If you don't care about losing the formatting in your spreadsheet, you can use [`pandas.DataFrame.bfill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.bfill.html) which fills empty holes ("NA/NaN values") with the next valid value in the same column.

See also [`DataFrame.fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html#pandas.DataFrame.fillna)

[image: Filled with pandas]

```py
import os
import pandas as pd

filename = r"spreadsheet.xlsx"
new_filename = r"spreadsheet_with_all_holes_backfilled_by_pandas.xlsx"

# Read the spreadsheet into a dataframe
df = pd.read_excel(filename)

# Backfill the holes. inplace=True means it updates the existing dataframe
df.bfill(inplace=True)

# Save the spreadsheet
df.to_excel(new_filename, index=False)

# Launch the new spreadsheet
os.startfile(new_filename)
```

If you want to keep the formatting, you can use [`openpyxl`](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) and manually check for holes and fill them manually.

[image: Filled by openpyxl]

```py
import os
import openpyxl

filename = r"spreadsheet.xlsx"
new_filename = r"spreadsheet_with_all_holes_filled_by_openpyxl.xlsx"

# Load the spreadsheet file
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename)

# Get the currently active sheet
ws = wb.active

# Loop over every column in the sheet
for column in ws.iter_cols():
    
    # Reset the value each new column
    last_valid_value = None
    
    # Then over every cell, starting from the bottom, heading up
    for cell in reversed(column):
        
        # Read the cell's value. We know it was empty if its value is None. If 
        # so, update its value with the last valid value (which has come from 
        # below in the spreadsheet), otherwise update the last_valid_value.
        value = cell.value
        if value is None:
            cell.value = last_valid_value
        else:
            last_valid_value = value

# Save the spreadsheet
wb.save(new_filename)

# Launch the new spreadsheet
os.startfile(new_filename)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can update the columns of the data like this after importing

```
data = pd.read_excel(excel_data)
data.set_axis(['Date ID', 'References', 'Amount', 'Weight'], axis='columns')
```